# why is this Unity 3D jump script doesn't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float MouseSensitivity;
    public float MoveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;
    
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Look around
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * MouseSensitivity, 0)));

        //Move
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MoveSpeed));
        
        //Jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            print("clicked");
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code and a picture of the player object when I'm trying to jump it doesn't work but it does print clicked I tried to do many things but nothing worked so if you know how to solve the issue please tell me

Comment: What is the value of the jumpForce variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RigidBody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) has a second parameter of type [`ForceMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) that defaults to `ForceMode.Force`. That particular `ForceMode` is only good for continual application of force (like a rocket's thruster). For a feature like jumping, you'll either want to use [`ForceMode.Impulse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html) or [`ForceMode.VelocityChange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.VelocityChange.html).

```cs
// Pick one or the other
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Also, make sure your `jumpForce` value isn't tiny or it'll be an unnoticeably small "jump."

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, physics calculations should generally be calculated inside of `FixedUpdate()`. This is described in the unity documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

Edit: To make it more clear for the comment on my post. Input should be located inside of the `Update()` method whilst physics calculations should generally be calculated inside of the `FixedUpdate()` method.

If it is decided that you want to register input inside of Update() and physics calculations, based on that input, inside of FixedUpdate() then you would use a boolean switch.

Looking at your code I would say that either:

The mass of your `Rigidbody` is high and your `jumpForce` variable is too low, trying increasing the value of the `jumpForce` variable to see if the `GameObject` moves.

Your Rigidbody has the `Is Kinematic` checkbox selected.

`AddForce` is defaulting the `ForceMode` to `ForceMode.Force`, try using a different force mode like `ForceMode.Impulse` to deliver a quick force to the `GameObject`. In your case this would look like `rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This `FixedUpdate()` comment is incorrect.  `GetKeyDown` is single-frame input and has the potential to either get lost or cause double-input in `FixedUpdate()`.  `ForceMode.Impulse` doesn't require `FixedUpdate()` as it changes the body's velocity by the value of force / mass.  Only `ForceMode.Force` and `ForceMode.Acceleration` (neither of which should be used for a jump) would need to be in a `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: The Unity documentation demonstrates the use of ForceMode.Impulse inside of FixedUpdate(), see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html. Your point regarding the single-frame input just means that the Input should be inside the Update() function, not necessarily the application of physics. It is common for Update() to use a boolean switch to apply physics changes inside of FixedUpdate(). I will edit my answer to make this clear but I do not necessarily believe your comment when the Unity documentation demonstrates otherwise.

Comment: That documentation is for a simple example but is still incorrect to be polling single-frame input in `FixedUpdate()`. [Here is a forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-with-fixedupdate-avoiding-input-loss-with-high-frame-rates.619483/) with a Unity engineer explaining that doing so will result in lost input.  This is a big part of why Unity is [reworking the entirety of their Input System to be event based.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Settings.html)